# JFrame Delete Selected Object Only

Tags: java, swing

How do I delete selected object?

I have 2 ways of Deletions which are as follows:

- Right click to delete specific/selected object.
- Clear button to delete/clear all objects in the window.

Unfortunately, the right click did not work as expected.
For example, I was supposed to right click on any objects and choose the "Delete" option which when then remove that particular object from the window. However, whichever objects that I wish to remove by selecting on it.. Upon clicking delete, it clears the whole windows instead.

I think the problem should be part of the codes shown below.

```
        Shape clickShape = null;
        Shape dragShape = null; 


        int prevDragX; 
        int prevDragY; 
        // ------------------------------------------------------

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent clickEvent) {
            if (dragShape != null) {
                return;
            }

            int x = clickEvent.getX(); // x-coordinate of point
            int y = clickEvent.getY(); // y-coordinate of point
            clickShape = null;
            for (int i = shapes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // check shapes from
                                                            // front to back
                Shape s = (Shape) shapes.get(i);
                if (s.containsPoint(x, y)) {
                    //dragShape = s;
                    //prevDragX = x;
                    //prevDragY = y;
                    clickShape = s;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Continue from here
            if (clickShape == null) {
                return;
            } else if (clickEvent.isPopupTrigger()) {
                click.show(this, x - 10, y - 2);
            } else if (clickEvent.isShiftDown()) {
                shapes.remove(clickShape);
                shapes.add(clickShape);
                repaint();
            } else {

                dragShape = clickShape;
                prevDragX = x;
                prevDragY = y;
            }

        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent clickEvent) {
            // User has moved the mouse. Move the dragged shape by the same
            // amount.
            if (dragShape == null) {
                return;
            }
            int x = clickEvent.getX();
            int y = clickEvent.getY();
            //if (dragShape != null) {
                dragShape.moveTo(x - prevDragX, y - prevDragY);
                prevDragX = x;
                prevDragY = y;
                repaint(); // redraw canvas to show shape in new position
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent clickEvent) {
            // User has released the mouse. Move the dragged shape, then set
            // shapeBeingDragged to null to indicate that dragging is over.
            if (dragShape == null) {
                return;
            }
            int x = clickEvent.getX();
            int y = clickEvent.getY();
            if (clickEvent.isPopupTrigger()) {
                click.show(this, x - 10, y - 2);
            } else {
                dragShape.moveTo(x - prevDragX, y - prevDragY);
                if (dragShape.left >= getSize().width || dragShape.top >= getSize().height
                        || dragShape.left + dragShape.width < 0 || dragShape.top + dragShape.height < 0) { // shape                                                                                                                                                                             
                    shapes.remove(dragShape); // remove shape from list
                }
                repaint();
            }
            dragShape = null;
        }
```

Comment: My object is referring to shapes added into the windows frame

Comment: What's the point of removing the shape and adding it back in the next line ?

Comment: Well, you have a single `remove(...)` statement, so add some debug statements to your code so see when that code is executed. We can't debug your code for you.

Comment: I have 2 different functionalities. For example, if there are 2 different shapes overlapping and i wish to bring the earlier shape to overlap on top of the other, I would have to press SHIFT key to do so.

Another would be, right click and delete the object permanently which is having issue at this moment.